# Sharing eventloops b/w different netty clients

Tags: netty

Exploring netty a bit and I had this question about sharing eventloops b/w different clients. Imagine an application has 2 different netty based clients. Is it correct / a good practice to share eventloop groups b/w these two clients? Motivation behind this is to limit the total number of eventloop threads created in the system as a whole. Is it correct and threadsafe to do so?

Some netty based clients do allow specifying eventLoopGroups when creating them (eg: https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/http/nio/netty/NettyNioAsyncHttpClient.Builder.html#eventLoopGroup(software.amazon.awssdk.http.nio.netty.SdkEventLoopGroup))

But I'm not sure if in general it's always safe to share eventLoopGroup b/w any 2 netty based clients? What about when an eventLoopGroup that's used to bootstrap and server is also used to create such a client?

Tried sharing eventloopgroup b/w a netty server and an aws s3 client, but client started misbehaving with some netty exceptions.